# What is the story with 64 reserved address limit on Juniper's DHCP server?

Tags: juniper, screenos

It's a very strange limitation, any way to increase it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a terribly clearly worded question sorry - do you mean how you can only define 64 IP addresses or ranges per subnet? If so I don't see how that's a problem at all - maybe you could explain why it's a problem. If that's not what you mean then please let us know.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was 64 IP addresses for reserved DHCP addresses on any interface of Juniper security appliances. The problem with this is that we need to be able to reserve at least 200 IPs but ScreenOS gives an error "IP list full".

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying - that's just a limitation (poor design in my mind) - that said I wouldn't be using that box for my DHCP anyway, you'd be better off with a proper DHCP server I think.

Comment: For Juniper engineers/management reading this. It's a silly limitation - having a separate DHCP server just because you need more then 64 reserved IP seems a bit strange.